# Do type guards only narrow the type when true is returned?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I was under the impression that a type guard which takes multiple types `instanceOfA(arg: A | B | C): arg is A`, would narrow the type to either `A` (when the guard returns `true`) or `B | C` (when the guard returns `false`)

However in the case of `instanceOfB` below, returning `false` seem to narrow the type to `never`, while `true` doesn't narrow it at all. Do type guards in fact only narrow the type if `true` is returned? Or am I misunderstanding the results, in which case, why does the narrowing to `never` occur?

```ts
// Structures
interface A {
    value: string
    children: B[]
}

interface B {
    value: string
}

// Example functions
function doSomething1(arg: A | B) {
    if (instanceOfA(arg)) {
        console.log(`A: ${arg.value}`) // Type of arg is A
    } else {
        console.log(`B: ${arg.value}`) // Type of arg is B
    }
}

function doSomething2(arg: A | B) {
    if (instanceOfB(arg)) {
        console.log(`B: ${arg.value}`) // Type of arg is A | B
    } else {
        console.log(`A: ${arg.value}`) // Type of arg is never
    }
}

// Typeguards
function instanceOfA(ab: A | B): ab is A {
    return ab.hasOwnProperty('children')
}

function instanceOfB(ab: A | B): ab is B {
    return !ab.hasOwnProperty('children')
}
```

Comment: `A` is a subtype of `B`; the compiler does not think that something can be an `A` without being a `B`.  If the absence of the `children` property really means you don't have a `B`, then maybe you should add `children?: never` to `B`'s definition and [try again](https://tsplay.dev/wEDrgW).  Does that meet your needs? If not, please elaborate on what use case fails.

Comment: For my real-code use case I can just use the `instanceOfA` check, I am just asking because I want to understand the issue properly. I think your explanation makes sense (though wouldn't `B` be a subtype of `A`?), so an interface that can "fit" into another interface is automatically considered to be a subtype, and the typeguard returning "not subtype" also results in "not main type"?

Comment: "wouldn't `B` be a subtype of `A`?"  No, "is a subtype of" , "is assignable to", and "extends" are (mostly) synonymous.   Subtype does not mean "has fewer known properties" at all; it means "is more specific".  Your `A` extends `B` because it adds a `children` property, making it more specific.  According to your definitions, any `A` is also a `B`.  You could say that `A` is a special sort of `B` that has a `children` property.  Absence of properties is not implied by absence of declaration.  This is how structural subtyping works.  I'm happy to write it up when I get a chance.

Comment: That seems like a fundamental aspect of Typescript I've managed to completely misunderstand, haha. That was very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, is this a theoretical question or are you having a real-world issue? if it's the second, I'd say it's just wrong identifying a type by what property it doesn't have.

If you read [the narrowing section in the typescript book](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) they have an example where they use a type guard to differentiate a `Fish` from a `Bird` by checking if the pet can swim (which in itself is a quite generous assumption). But what you are doing (transformed to the bird, fish example) is basically saying: "If it's can't swim it must be a bird". Doing that just doesn't seem particularly logical *(as pointed out in the comments that this assumption is valid if there are only fish and birds to choose from)*.

I don't think the `instanceOfB` is sensible. TypeScript allows assigning different types to each other if they have enough overlap, and `A` will always be assignable to `B` because it completely covers all properties it has. As soon as you add some property to `B` that `A` doesn't have the issue will go away.

For example this would be perfectly fine typescript:

```
const a: A = {value: 'this is a', children: []};
const b: B = {value: 'this is b'};

function printValue(subject: {value: string}) {
    console.log(subject.value);
}
```

And your check would start working if you did this (for example):

```
interface B {
    value: string
    other: string;
}
```

Comment: If the options are `fish` and `bird` and I know only a fish can swim, then "can't swim = bird" seems pretty logical to me.

Comment: @DBS, yes, if the only options are `Fish` and `Bird` that is a valid assumption. But what if those are not the only options? And I stand by the argument that one shouldn't identify an object by what property it doesn't have, because you most likely want to reveal a property and then use it. So actually checking for it is more practical.

Comment: @DBS, yes, if the only options are `Fish` and `Birth` that is a valid assumption. But what if those are not the only options? And still, I stand by the argument that one shouldn't identify an object by what property it doesn't have, because you most likely want to revel a property and then use it. So actually checking for it is more practical.

Comment: @DBS yeah I don't think the `instanceOfB` check makes any sense. TypeScript allows assigning different types to each other when they have enough overlap, and `A` will always be assignable to `B` because it completely covers it. As soon as you add some property to `B` that `A` doesn't have the issue will go away.